# can't connect localhost mysql database with android app : Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am using JSON and php script to fetch data from mysql database

```
                try
                {               
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                "http://192.168.1.100:61896/JsonDemoDatabase/src/jsonscript.php",
                postParameters);

                String result = response.toString();

                try
                {
                    returnString = "";
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        pass = json_data.getString("Password");
                        if(pass.equals(password.getText().toString()))
                        {

                            //Get an output to the screen
                            tv.setVisibility(1);
                            returnString += "Login Successfull";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tv.setVisibility(1);
                            returnString += "Login Fail";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }
```

I got Error as mention below :
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Comment: Did you check your response data?

Comment: In particular, `toString()` on `response` may not be giving you the JSON that you are expecting.